# Inline type annotations vs. stub results in different mypy behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.6, mypy, python-typing

My project depends on another project that stores the type annotations in stub files. Within the [.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5d92a6cc30013a3687d4f82ad5030bd047ed9755/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L87) file the other project defines a base class that I need to inherit from a follows

```py
# within a .py file

class Foo:
    def bar(self, *baz):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

In the corresponding [.pyi](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5d92a6cc30013a3687d4f82ad5030bd047ed9755/torch/nn/modules/module.pyi.in#L24) stub they annotate it as follows:

```py
# whitin a .pyi file

from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Callable

T_co = TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)

class Foo(Generic[T_co]):
    bar: Callable[..., T_co]
```

For my project I want to do the type annotations inline, i.e. in the .py file, and tried to do it in a subclass of `Foo` as follows:

```py
# within a .py file

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def bar(self, baz: float) -> str:
        pass
```

Running [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) on this results in the following error

```
error: Signature of "bar" incompatible with supertype "Foo"
```

If I remove my inline annotations and add this to a .pyi stub

```py
# within a .pyi file

class SubFoo(Foo):
    bar: Callable[[float], str]
```

`mypy` runs fine.

I thought that both methods are equivalent, but apparently that is not the case. Can someone explain to me how they differ and what I need to change to make this work with inline annotations?

---

It became clear in the comments of @Michael0x2a answer that the error is only reproducible if you indeed use a .py and a .pyi file. You can download the examples from above [here](https://gist.github.com/pmeier/4439755ed0add02dd22eab81c5d7d34e).

Answer (score 2):

As a caveat, it's unclear to me exactly what your code looks like. You have several different versions of `Foo` defined and I'm not sure exactly which one you're trying to subclass -- your question is missing a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

But I'm guessing you're trying to do something like this?

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self, *baz: float) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def bar(self, baz: float) -> str:
        pass
```

If so, the problem is that according to the signature of the base class, it'd be legal to do something like this, since `Foo.bar(...)` is defined to accept a variable number of arguments.

```
f = Foo()
f.bar(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

But if we try using your subclass in place of Foo, this code would fail since it only accepts one argument.

This idea that a subclass should always be capable of taking the place of the parent class without causing type errors and without violating the existing preconditions and postconditions of your code is known as the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

But in that case, why does doing the following type check?

```py
class Foo:
    bar: Callable[..., str]

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def bar(self, baz: float) -> str:
        pass
```

This is because since the parent type's signature is `Callable[..., str]`, mypy actually ends up skipping checking the function arguments altogether. The `...` is basically saying "please don't bother type checking anything related to my arguments".

It's sort of similar to how using the `Any` type lets you mix dynamic types with static ones. Similarly, `Callable[..., str]` lets you express callables with dynamic/undetermined signatures.

Contrast this with the following program:

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
        pass

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def bar(self, baz: float) -> str:
        pass
```

Unlike the previous program, this one does *not* type check -- while `Foo.bar` still can accept any arguments, the "structure" of the arguments in this case is not left flexible and mypy will now insist that your subclass must also be capable of accepting an arbitrary number of arguments.

---

As a final note, it's important to note that none of this behavior has anything to do with whether your type hints are defined in a stub or not. Rather, it all comes down to what the actual types of your functions are.

Comment: 1. Maybe I did not make it clear enough. The first block of `Foo` and `SubFoo` are defined in the .py file while the second block is defined within the .pyi file. I will change my question to better reflect this. 2. I'm still trying to process your answer, but as far as I see you did not answer how I would annotate a method with `Callable[..., Any]` inline. Could you add this to your answer?

Comment: @Fugu_Fish -- to annotate a function as being `Callable[..., Any]` inline, just do `bar: Callable[..., Any]`. This is valid syntax in Python files as of Python 3.7, though you'll end up having to assign bar a function after-the-fact which is inconvenient. However, there's no way of defining a function in the normal way and giving it the exact same signature as `Callable[..., Any]`. The closest alternative would be `def bar(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any`.

Comment: Also, I'm still not able to reproduce your error message, btw. Maybe you can try coming up with an example using the [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net)? I'd start by copying-and-pasting the relevant segments of your pyi and py files into the playground -- for Python 3, both file types use the same syntax and type checking rules, so you should be able to distill your code down to a single file.

Comment: 1. I'm using Python 3.6. Sorry, I wasn't aware that this could make a difference. I'll add it to the question. 2. Indeed, I'm also unable to reproduce the error in the playground (or locally in single file for that matter). It seems that the split .py and a .pyi file is necessary to reproduce. I'll try to add these files as examples to my question.